# If the input tag is initialized to null, the array containing e.target.files is empty

Tags: javascript, upload

Hi I'm uploading a folder right now, but when I upload the same folder again, there was a problem that it couldn't be uploaded. There was a problem that the data was empty the moment I set it to null.

```
const uploadFolders = [];
let uploadFolderTemplate = ``;

function upload(e) {
    const files = e.target.files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        uploadFolders.push(files);

        uploadFolderTemplate = `
            <div class="card folder-list-info">
                <div class="card-header" style="display: inline-flex;">
                    <span>${files[0].path}</span>
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" style="margin-left: auto">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="ext-box">
                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="colum-box">
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="exports-data-file-box">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

    }
}


const folderUploadInput = document.querySelector('.folder-upload-input');

folderUploadInput.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.value = null;
});

folderUploadInput.addEventListener('change', upload)
```

Comment: "There was a problem that the data was empty the moment I set it to null." I might completely misunderstand you, but is that not the point of setting it to null...?

Comment: It is correct that the array is empty by setting it to null. But I've already pushed to the global array and I don't know if it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the `e.target.files` object into an other array, and then later on you set the value of `e.target.files` to `null`. This does not work as you think it would, as pushing an object into an array stores it as a *reference* and not as a *copy*. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/3007852) for a better explanation of what's going on when you're setting `e.target.files = null`.

To fix your problem you will need to store it as copy. There are a few ways to get a copy of a object in Javascript, but i prefer [this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
const files = Object.assign({}, e.target.files);
```